# Helloworld. Что я делаю не так?

Tags: windows-7, ассемблер, fasm

```
format PE console
entry start
section '.main' readable executable
start:
mov eax,0x018c
mov ebx,1
mov ecx,cs01
mov edx,$-cs01
int 0x2e
mov eax, 0x0190
mov ebx,0
int 0x2e
section '.const' readable
cs01 db 'Hello, world!',13,10,0
```

Попытался написать на fasm обычный helloworld под win7, однако не работает. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: @KryDos [System Call Instructions][1]


  [1]: http://www.codemachine.com/article_syscall.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Начнем с того, что int 0x2e вызывать можно лишь в 32х битных системах. Во вторых формат вызова функции 0x2e

```
INT 2E - Windows NT - NATIVE API

    EAX = function number 
    EDX = address of parameter block
Return: ???
```

Далее смотрим:

```
mov eax,0x018c ; 396 в win7 sp 1 NtWriteFile
...
mov eax, 0x0190; 400 тамже NtYealdExecution
```

т.е. строго говоря, все что передается в параметрах в твоем коде - мусор.

для твоего случая, больше подходит программа вида:

```
format PE console
entry start

include 'win32a.inc'

section '.main' code executable
start:
        push hello
        call [printf]
        pop ecx

        push 10000
        call [Sleep] ;пауза в 10 секунд

        push 0
        call [ExitProcess]

section '.rdata' data readable
        hello db 'Hello world!', 10, 0

section '.idata' data readable import
        library kernel32, 'kernel32.dll', \
                msvcrt,   'msvcrt.dll'
        import kernel32, ExitProcess, 'ExitProcess', Sleep, 'Sleep'
        import msvcrt, printf, 'printf'
```

ps. под x64 работать не будет(Используй эмулятор по типу DosBox):

```
format MZ

entry main:start            ; program entry point
stack 100h                ; stack size

segment main                ; main program segment
start:
mov    ax,text
mov    ds,ax
mov    dx,hello
call    extra:write_text
mov    ax,4C00h
int    21h
segment text
hello db 'Hello world!',24h
segment extra
write_text:
mov    ah,9
int    21h
retf
```